# How Do I Split a Mule Payload into a MySQL Database?

Tags: split, mule, payload

I am looking to solve a relatively simple problem with a Mule flow. I am working through some easy examples as I learn how to manipulate and transform data. The following code sets an example payload of strings separated by commas (one,two,three,four).

The split expression gives each part its own value then 'for each' one puts it into a dummy database.

What this does is put each individual payload into colOne of the database until each part of the payload is complete (colOne - row1 = one, row2 = two and so on).

However, is there a simple way to have each part of the split payload go into the next column (i.e. colOne, row1 = 'one'... colTwo, row1 = 'Two' and so on)?

I can not use the 'for each' and set each part of the payload to a variable but then I get 'one, 'two', 'three, 'four' on a row but repeated over four rows.

Thanks guys,
My code is attached...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" user="Stuart" password="sqlsr3270" database="test" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
    <flow name="sampleFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="Inbound HTTP" allowedMethods="GET"/>
        <set-payload value="five,six,seven,eight" doc:name="Set Sample Payload"/>
        <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.split(&quot;,&quot;)]" doc:name="Split String"/>
        <logger message="#['\n\n\nPayload before insert: ' + payload[0] + ', ' + payload[1] + ', ' + payload[2] + ', ' + payload[3]]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
            <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO testtable (colOne) VALUES(#[payload])]]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:insert>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Post your actual input which needs to be splitted?.Need to know the type of payload

Comment: Have you tried bulk Insert mode